# Positioning an image over div tag/tags in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, image, css, positioning

This is what I am trying to achieve:

An image positioned in between two separate div tag like facebook profile page:

[image]

I searched here but the solutions did not help much. It got positioned as I wanted but since it is bootstrap and it should responsive, when the screen size decreases the image position gets changed, which I do not want.

Here is the code(which might not be proper as I was just testing) -

HTML -

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbo" id="custjumbo">
            <h1>This is a jumbotron... </h1>
            <h2>Let's see what can we make of it..</h2>

            <br>

            <img src="images/tiger.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Tiger" 
            width="304" height="236">
        </div>
</div>
```

The CSS -

```
.container {
    background-color: cadetblue;

    }

    .jumbo {

    margin-top:20px;
    position: relative;
    }
    .img-thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 200px;
}
    img {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
    }
```

This is what I got after:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the img-thumbnail to position: relative and use 'bottom: -60px' instead of positioning absolute, that can reposition the image without the use of absolute positioning

Answer (score 0):

check it

```css
.container {
    background-color: cadetblue;
    width:100%;

    }

    .jumbo {

    margin-top:20px;
    position: relative;
    }
    .img-thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -90px;
    left:15%;
}
    img {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
    }
    .bottom-div {
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;}
```

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-sclae=1">
</head>
<div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbo" id="custjumbo">
            <h1>This is a jumbotron... </h1>
            <h2>Let's see what can we make of it..</h2>

            <br>

            <img src="images/tiger.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Tiger" 
            width="304" height="236">

        </div>
                    <div class="bottom-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: well Thank you for your effort but as I mentioned it is bootstrap and it should be scaled properly, so when I squeeze the screen size  a bit smaller then the image gets out of the container area.

Comment: make the position of thumbnail relative

Comment: check it in full page...it is responsive